# What is the value about these arrays in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int myChr[4][8];
    printf("%x\n",myChr);
    printf("%x\n",&myChr);
    printf("%x\n",*myChr);
    return 0;
}
```

After executing the above program, I get the same address as output. Do they own different value or all of them have same value?  How to prove that? (*Maybe need to assume values to array, I don't know)

Comment: Do some research on SO and you will find good answers on earlier asked questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myChar` is a `int [4][8]`.

In the `printf` expression:

- `myChar`  is of type `int (*)[8]` (after application of C array to pointer conversion rule from `int [4][8]`)
- `&myChar` is of type `int (*) [4][8]`
- `*myChar` is of type `int *` (after application of C array to pointer conversion rule from `int [4]`)

All the expressions have different types but they point to the same memory address, that is:

```
 (void *) myChar == (void *) &myChar == (void *) *myChar
```

Note that the valid way to print a pointer value is to use `p` conversion specifier and cast the pointer to `void *` if it is of a different type.

Answer (score 4):

- `myChr` is the address on the stack of your array.
- `&mychr`, in this case, is probably going to give you the same value as it is the address of the pointer on the stack.
- `*myChr` is the address of 1st entry of `myChr[4][8]` entry, which in the case is still the original address.
- `**myChar` would give you the value of `myChr[0][0]` - in this case garbage as you have not actually assigned anything to your array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are simply named extents of memory. So the address of an array is the address of the extent it occupies. At the same time it is the address of the first element of the array because it occupies the initial part of the extent.

Thus you have:

this statement

```
printf("%x\n",myChr);
```

displays the address of the first element of the array because array name is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element;

this statement

```
printf("%x\n",&myChr);
```

displays the address of the array that is the same address as above because it is the address of the allocated extent;

this statement

```
printf("%x\n",*myChr);
```

displays the same address. Why? As I have already said the name of the array is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. The element of the array is in turn a one-dimensional array. So in expression this one-dimensional array `*myChr` (the first element of the original two-dimensional array) in turn is converted to pointer to its first element.

So in all three cases you display this address :)

```
&myChr[0][0]
```